# Eager execution: gradient computation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I m wondering why is this very simple gradient computation not working correctly. It is actually generating a [None, None] vector. Obviously, this is not the desired output.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

a = tf.constant(0.)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    b = 2 * a
da, db = tape.gradient(a + b, [a, b])
print(da)
print(db)
```

Expected Output:
da = 3 and db = 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two minor issues with the code snippet you posted:

1. The `a + b` computation is happening outside the context of the tape, so it is not being recorded. Note that `GradientTape` can only differentiate computation that is recorded. Computing `a + b` inside the tape context will fix that.
2. Source tensors need to be "watched". There are two ways to signal to the tape that a tensor should be watched: (a) explicitly invoking [`tape.watch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#watch), or (b) Using a `tf.Variable` (all variables are watched), see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#class_gradienttape)

Long story short, two trivial modifications to your snippet do the trick:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

a = tf.constant(0.)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(a)
    b = 2 * a
    c = a + b
da, db = tape.gradient(c, [a, b])
print(da)
print(db)
```

Hope that helps.